# SQL connection still open even after deleting it

Tags: qt, qt4

The second time I try to connect to a database, I get this message:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'CompanyDatabase' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
```

I delete the Model that I had previously used, I delete all connections, and I close the database. Below I have included the widget that opens the CompanyWidget as a modal dialog, because I think it might be relevant how I am opening/closing the widget which uses the database. Cany anyone explain why this database is still in use?

EDIT: If I change the QSqlDatabase member to a pointer and create it using:

```
this->CompanyDatabase = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "CompanyDatabase"));
```

and delete it before re-adding the database:

```
  if(this->CompanyDatabase)
    {
    delete this->CompanyDatabase;
    this->CompanyDatabase = NULL;
    }
```

then the error goes away. Why is this any different then the way I was doing it with the non-pointer member?

EditCompanyWidget.h

```
#ifndef EditCompanyWidget_H
#define EditCompanyWidget_H

#include "ui_EditCompanyWidget.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

class QSqlTableModel;


class EditCompanyWidget : public QDialog, private Ui::EditCompanyWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

  EditCompanyWidget(QSqlDatabase);
  ~EditCompanyWidget();

public slots:

  void on_btnExit_clicked();

protected:
  QSqlTableModel* Model;
};

#endif
```

EditCompanyWidget.cpp

```
#include "EditCompanyWidget.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>

EditCompanyWidget::EditCompanyWidget(QSqlDatabase database) : QDialog(NULL)
{
  setupUi(this);

  //QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel;
  this->Model = new QSqlTableModel(NULL, database);
  this->Model->setTable("CompanyTable");
  this->Model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
  //model->setFilter(QString("id=%1").arg(1));
  this->Model->select();

  this->tableView->setModel(this->Model);
}

EditCompanyWidget::~EditCompanyWidget()
{
  if(this->Model)
    {
    std::cout << "destructor Deleting..." << std::endl;
    delete this->Model;
    this->Model = NULL;
    }
}


void EditCompanyWidget::on_btnExit_clicked()
{
  this->Model->revertAll();
  if(this->Model)
    {
    std::cout << "btnExit Deleting..." << std::endl;
    delete this->Model;
    this->Model = NULL;
    }
  //this->setResult(QDialog::Rejected);
  this->reject();
}
```

MainWidget.h

```
#ifndef TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget_H
#define TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget_H

#include "ui_TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

class TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget : public QMainWindow, private Ui::TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
  void on_btnNewCompany_clicked();
  void on_btnEditCompany_clicked();

protected:
  QSqlDatabase CompanyDatabase;
};

#endif
```

MainWidget.cpp

```
#include "TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget.h"

#include "EditCompanyWidget.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>

TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget::TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
}


void TimeTrackerConfigurationWidget::on_btnEditCompany_clicked()
{
//   QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Database File", ".", "Image Files (*.sqlite)");
//
//   if(fileName.toStdString().empty())
//     {
//     std::cout << "Filename was empty." << std::endl;
//     return;
//     }

  QString fileName = "test.sqlite";

  if(!QFile::exists(fileName))
    {
    std::cerr << "File does not exist!" << std::endl;
    return;
    }

  this->CompanyDatabase.close();
  //QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("CompanyDatabase");
  //QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

  // Delete all connections
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < QSqlDatabase::connectionNames().size(); ++i)
    {
    //QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("TestConnection");
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::connectionNames()[i]);
    }


  this->CompanyDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "CompanyDatabase");
  //this->CompanyDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
  this->CompanyDatabase.setDatabaseName(fileName);
  if (!this->CompanyDatabase.open())
    {
    std::cerr << "Could not open database" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << this->CompanyDatabase.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    return;
    }

  EditCompanyWidget* editCompanyWidget = new EditCompanyWidget(this->CompanyDatabase);
  editCompanyWidget->exec();
  delete editCompanyWidget;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i got it wrong, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says it clearly: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase. You have to destroy all the queries objects and the QSqlDatabase connection objects you have instantiated before removing the connection. When you delete the pointer, you're actually doing this. With your previous code, you weren't.

Comment: It seems awfully strange though that you can't keep an object as a member variable and then call some kind of "disconnect" function on it to simulate deleting it?

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? I don't know whether a way exists or not, sorry, but I don't think it is necessary. By using the static QSqlDatabase::database(...) you can do whatever you want. By also using the overridden operator= you can assign to objects, without copying I guess, so without overhead.

Comment: Consider also a little search for this error. It has already been asked everywhere, also here on stack overflow. You might find more information.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the connection has to be added and removed using static functions. Wouldn't it be much easier if you could just control the connection with something like ConnectionObject myConnection = SqlDatabase(...)?

Comment: Easier? Well, it is up to you. I find it excellent like this. But... have you read my last comment? That is exactly what you do. You addDatabase(..) to create a connection with a name, you can later retrieve your connection object with the database(...) method like you said: QSqlDatabase myConnection = QSqlDatabase::database(connectionName, ...) and you can remove the connection with removeConnection. How can that be simpler? All of this is clearly stated in the documentation, with code snippets.